# Retrieve one contact with python gdata.contacts.client

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, gdata, google-contacts-api

I try to retrieve a contact with `gdata.contacts.client` :

Auth :

```python
class ModifyMe(webapp.RequestHandler):

    @login_required
    def get(self):
        """print contacts"""
        current_user = users.get_current_user()
        access_token_key = 'access_token_%s' % current_user.user_id()
        token = gdata.gauth.ae_load(access_token_key)
        gcontacts_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(source = SETTINGS['APP_NAME'])
        gcontacts_client = token.authorize(gcontacts_client)
```

According to API documentation, i tried this :

```
        contact = gcontacts_client.GetContact('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yohann%40mail.info/base/2e091c5e9b3d60b4')
```

But i had this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~yoyocontacts/2.359462823193148133/main.py", line 246, in PrintContact
    contact = gd_client.GetContacts('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yohann%mail.info/base/2e091c5e9b3d60b4')
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~yoyocontacts/2.359462823193148133/gdata/contacts/client.py", line 201, in get_contacts
    desired_class=desired_class, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~yoyocontacts/2.359462823193148133/gdata/client.py", line 640, in get_feed
    **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~yoyocontacts/2.359462823193148133/gdata/client.py", line 319, in request
    RequestError)
RequestError: Server responded with: 400,
```

Ok, try again :

```
        contact = gcontacts_client.GetContact('www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yohann%40mail.info/base/2e091c5e9b3d60b4')
```

An other error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~yoyocontacts/2.359462880270555204/main.py", line 246, in PrintContact
    contact = gd_client.GetContact('www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yohann%40lepage.info/base/2e091c5e8b3760b4')
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~yoyocontacts/2.359462880270555204/gdata/contacts/client.py", line 89, in get_contact
    desired_class=desired_class, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~yoyocontacts/2.359462880270555204/gdata/client.py", line 652, in get_entry
    desired_class=desired_class, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~yoyocontacts/2.359462880270555204/gdata/client.py", line 267, in request
    uri=uri, auth_token=auth_token, http_request=http_request, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~yoyocontacts/2.359462880270555204/atom/client.py", line 119, in request
    http_request.method, str(http_request.uri)))
MissingHost: No host provided in request GET https://Nonewww.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yohann%40mail.info/base/2e091c5e8b3760b4
```

Oh wait ! https:// **None** www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yohann%40mail.info/base/2e091c5e8b3760b4

How fix this behavior ? Why there is **None** between https:// and uri ?

PS : `feed_groups = gd_client.GetGroup(group_url)` works like a charm...

PS : [Source file](https://raw.github.com/2xyo/google-contacts/master/main.py)Source file function ModifyMe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong url, the correct one looks like the following:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/<email>/base/<contactId>
```

Where `<email>` is the email address of the user you are requesting the contact for (obviously, you must be authorized to access those contacts). This field can also assume the value "default" to replace the email address of the currently authenticated user.

`contactId` is the identifier of the contact as returned by the API. I think you got this right.

Also, make sure the protocol is `https` and not `http`.

Comment: If i try with the url `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yohann@mail.info/base/2e091c5e8b3d61b4`, i also get http 400. Where `yohann@mail.com` is the email (google apps account) of the user. I get this url by retrieve by listing users of a group `entry.id.text`.

Comment: Try sending the same request with the OAuth 2.0 Playground (https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/), the 400 response code should also include a more detailed error message telling what's wrong with your request.

Comment: It works with `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yohann%40lepage.info/base/2e091c5e8b3d60b4`..

Comment: @Yohann I think it's because the token are not stored permanently.